# Can I instantiate an object in Dancer to return a value to display?

Tags: perl, dancer, moo, moops

I have the following code in my Dancer app module:

```
package Deadlands;
use Dancer ':syntax';
use Dice;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {
    my ($dieQty, $dieType);
    $dieQty = param('dieQty');
    $dieType = param('dieType');
    if (defined $dieQty && defined $dieType) {
        return Dice->new(dieType => $dieType, dieQty => $dieQty)->getStandardResult();
    }
    template 'index';
};

true;
```

I have a Moops class called Dice.pm that works just fine if I test it with a .pl file, but when I try to access it through the web browser, I get the following error: **Can't locate object method "new" via package "Dice" (perhaps you forgot to load "Dice"?)**.

Can I do this with Dancer?

Here is the pertinent code from Dice.pm:

```
use 5.14.3;
use Moops;

class Dice 1.0 {
    has dieType => (is => 'rw', isa => Int, required => 1);
    has dieQty => (is => 'rw', isa => Int, required => 1);
    has finalResult => (is => 'rw', isa => Int, required => 0);

    method getStandardResult() {
        $self->finalResult(int(rand($self->dieType()) + 1));
        return $self->finalResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you `use Dice;`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The error message suggests that they *dont* have `use Dice;`

Comment: Use Dice is indeed at the top of the script. I updated the code to show the whole script.

Comment: Is Dice a module that you have created? or one from CPAN?

Comment: Dice.pm is a module I wrote.

Comment: You might want to post the [relevant] code from `Dice.pm`.

Comment: I have edited to show Dice.pm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to say you forgot the `package Dice` in your `Dice.pm`, but after reading up on Moops I am confused about the namespaces.

Let's take a look at the [documentation for Moops](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops).

> If you use Moops within a package other than main, then package names
>   used within the declaration are "qualified" by that outer package,
>   unless they contain "::". So for example:
>
> ```
> package Quux;
> use Moops;
>
> class Foo { }       # declares Quux::Foo
>
> class Xyzzy::Foo    # declares Xyzzy::Foo
>    extends Foo { }  # ... extending Quux::Foo
>
> class ::Baz { }     # declares Baz
> ```

If the `class Dice` is in `Dice.pm` it will actually become `Dice::Dice` if I read this correctly. So you would have to `use Dice` and create your object with `Dice::Dice->new`.

In order to make the package `Dice` within `Dice.pm` using Moops, I believe you need to declare the class like this:

```
class ::Dice 1.0 {
    #  ^------------- there are two colons here!

    has dieType => (is => 'rw', isa => Int, required => 1);
    has dieQty => (is => 'rw', isa => Int, required => 1);
    has finalResult => (is => 'rw', isa => Int, required => 0);

    method getStandardResult() {
        $self->finalResult(int(rand($self->dieType()) + 1));
        return $self->finalResult();
    }
}
```

You can then do:

```
use Dice;
Dice->new;
```

Comment: I must say find this behavior a little bit strange.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions, but alas I get the same error. Thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: I changed your implementation, and it works! I declared the class with the double colons, but instantiated like this: Dice->new

Comment: That's what I meant you ought to do. Sorry if that was not clear. ;)